# c# event handling: best practice to avoid thread contention and threadpool draining

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, thread-safety, threadpool

When events trigger, they use threads from the threadpool. So if you have a bunch of events that trigger faster than they return, you drain your threadpool. So whenever you have an event handler method that doesn't have any other control to limit the rate of threads entering, and doesn't have any guarantee of returning quickly, and you're not painstakingly implementing 100% thread-safe code inside that method, it's probably best to implement some thread control. The obvious simple thing to do would be to lock() inside the event handling method, but if you do that, all the threads after the first one will block in queue, waiting to enter the lock region, hogging all your threads from threadpool.  It is probably better to detect another thread is inside this method, and quickly abort instead.

The question is:  I have a way of detecting another thread already running, and quickly aborting the subsequent threads.  But it doesn't seem very C#-ish due to the use of "const" and manually handling a locking flag at a low level.  Is there a better way?

This is basically a direct replication of the lock() functionality, but using a non-blocking Interlocked.Exchange, instead of using the blocking Monitor.Enter()

```
    public class FooGoo
    {
        private const int LOCKED = 0;            // could use any arbitrary value; I choose 0
        private const int UNLOCKED = LOCKED + 1; // any arbitrary value, != LOCKED
        private static int _myLock = UNLOCKED;
        void myEventHandler()
        {
            int previousValue = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _myLock, LOCKED);
            if ( previousValue == UNLOCKED )
            {
                try
                {
                    // some handling code, which may or may not return quickly
                    // maybe not threadsafe
                }
                finally
                {
                    _myLock = UNLOCKED;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // another thread is executing right now. So I will abort.
                //
                // optional and environment-specific, maybe you want to 
                // queue some event information or set a flag or something,
                // so you remember later that this thread aborted
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just found:  lock() is a shortcut for System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(x);
try { ... }
finally { System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(x); }  So this is already an improvement, to eliminate the const.  I guess the only thing left is to ask, does there exist any sort of non-blocking shortcut, like lock() to shorten all the above?

Comment: Event firing does _not_ use the threadpool.

Comment: @JohnSaunders at the very least, events resulting from system.timers.timer are executed on threadpool threads, as confirmed by viewing Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread. But that detail isn't central to the question anyway.

Comment: I bet it's not so much that the timer events are executed on threadpool threads, but rather that the .NET code which learns about the timer expiration was already running on a threadpool thread. I believe you'll find that, in general, events are raised on the same thread that detected the event.

Comment: @JohnSaunders again, it doesn't really matter, this is just a tangent, but to test this, I created a new console app, and inside of Main() created a bunch of timers, and in the event handling method, display info about currentthread. The originating thread, I put to an infinite sleep, to prevent the app from dying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, this is the best answer I have found.  Does there exist any shorthand equivalent of a non-blocking lock() to shorten this up?

```
static object _myLock;
void myMethod ()
{
    if ( Monitor.TryEnter(_myLock) )
    {
        try
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_myLock);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // then I failed to get the lock.  Optionally do stuff.
    }
}
```